# Why does List breaks the bitmaps added to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, bitmap

The bitmap basically gets obliterated when added into the List.
What am I doing wrong?

Does disposing the bitmap breaks the one added to the List?

```
List<Bitmap> _list = new List<Bitmap>();

public void MyMethod()
{
    using (var _bitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080))
    {
        _list.Add(_bitmap);
    }
}
```

I put breakpoints at the line `_list.Add(_bitmap);`, and this is the bitmap before adding:

[image: before]

And this is when it's in the List:

[image]

Comment: You're destroying the bitmap right after adding it to the list when you exit the `using` scope.

Comment: @AseemRajBaranwal: "All objects of non-primitive data types are passed by reference" - no, they're not. The value of `_bitmap` is indeed a reference, but that reference is passed by value to the `Add` method. Please see http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @AseemRajBaranwal Just to emphasise Jon Skeet's point. It's not only about bitmaps, in fact the exact opposite of your statement is the correct one: Almost everything is passed by value. The objects of non-primitive data types are also passed by value, but they are themselves references. So the references are passed by value.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for this precise clarification! Learnt something fundamental today.

Comment: @AseemRajBaranwal: Hooray - thanks for taking my comment in the constructive spirit it was intended :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your line

```
using (var _bitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080))
{
    _list.Add(_bitmap);
} //_bitmap  is destroyed here
```

`Bitmal` derives from [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) class which implements `IDisposable`, hence at the end of closure, `Dispose` will be called on `Bitmap`.

You might want to avoid using `using` in this scenario.

It worth to mention that `_list.Add(..)` adds a reference of created bitmap instance, and does not copy/clone it.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to express, for completeness, that adding an object to a list does not create a new object, as that seems to have been assumed by the asker (or they didn't realize why exactly the using statement is so preferred).

Comment: @HDL_CinC_Dragon I wasn't sure about this, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

> Does disposing the bitmap breaks the one added to the List?

Well, of course it does. The list doesn't have any bitmaps inside, it only has pointers to the bitmaps (i.e. pointer to the memory address where each bitmap is stored). So once you dispose the bitmap, the pointer is now pointing to a memory address that is empty.

If you're creating those bitmaps from files or other resources that you need to free, then clone the bitmap after creating it, dispose the original bitmap (you're already doing this with the `using()` statement), and add the clone to the list:

```
using (var _bitmap = new Bitmap("flower.png")) {
    Bitmap clone = Bitmap(_bitmap);
    _list.Add(clone);
}
```